# How to partially constrain VHDL arrays (elements)?

Tags: arrays, file, vhdl

I am trying to use unconstrained arrays in a VHDL-2008 testbench, but Modelsim (2020.1) gives an error if I try to declare a `file` type.

This simplified example reproduces the error:

```vhdl
entity tb is
end entity;

architecture arch of tb is
    
    type array_t is array(natural range<>) of bit_vector;
    subtype sub_t is array_t(open)(15 downto 0);
    type file_t is file of sub_t;
    
begin
end architecture;
```

> vcom -2008 tb.vhd
>
> # ** Error: tb.vhd(8): Cannot define file of an array whose element subtype is not fully
> constrained.

I am confused by this error message because, as far as I understand, the element subtype **is** fully constrained. I had a look in [VHDL 2008: Just the New Stuff](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742498) which says (in Section 3.1.2):

> If we want to define a partially constrained subtype, specifying index
> ranges for the elements but leaving the index range at the top level
> unspecified, we can use the reserved word **open** in place of an index
> range

So why do I get this error? As a sanity check, the following compiles without error:

```vhdl
entity tb is
end entity;

architecture arch of tb is
    
    type array_t is array(natural range<>) of bit_vector(15 downto 0);
    subtype sub_t is array_t;
    type file_t is file of sub_t;
    
begin
end architecture;
```

I don't really understand what the exact differences are between the declarations of `sub_t` in each case (and why one should work whereas the other fails).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.5 File types 5.5.1 General "The type mark in a file type definition defines the subtype of the values contained in the file. The type mark may denote either a fully constrained, a partially constrained, or an unconstrained subtype." The difference between the two subtype declarations is the unsuccessful one provides an array constraint which doesn't appear to be implemented correctly in this particular version of Modelsim (which would have been licensed by Intel/Altera at some point in the past regardless of their release). Also see 5.3.2 Array types 5.3.2.1 General.

Comment: 5. Types 5.1 General "A composite subtype is said to be *partially constrained* if it is neither unconstrained nor fully constrained." (Your first code example analyzes in a recent ghdl (1.0+).

Comment: ActiveHDL 12.0 also has no problem with the first example nor does it have an issue running and writing to a file.

Comment: I have raised tickets in the past, but usually takes a while for a fix. I no longer have a mentor account. Buty you have a workaround the should be acceptable.